# Нужны ли знаки препинания в предложении? 1

Tags: пунктуация

Но прежде под руководством главного балетмейстера РДК Инны Викторовны девушка прошла огромную школу в ансамбле "Юг".

Comment: Сегодня уже 2-е с утра. Опоздала.

Answer (score 1):

Распространенный обстоятельственный оборот желательно обособить:

Но прежде, **под руководством главного балетмейстера РДК Инны Викторовны,** девушка прошла огромную школу в ансамбле "Юг".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ: чисто субъективное, исключительно образное мнение**

**Почему мне хотелось бы, чтобы обстоятельство было обособлено.**

**1) "Вытянутое в длину",  предложение сложнее для прочтения,** в то время как при наличии обособления "двухэтажная конструкция" легче, воздушнее. (Эти 16 слов, следующих друг за другом, напомнили мне длинный грузовой состав или огромный плоский тяжеловесный гараж, который, **при избытке свободного места и недостатке воображения**, однажды построили под моим окном). И вывод: **Ажурность и стройность – они хороши как в архитектуре, так и в литературе тоже.**

**2) Семантика тоже неразделенная:** все ли факты равнозначны или есть деление на главные и второстепенные, - ничего этого не обозначено.

Comment: И это вам не нравятся краткие ответы типа "нет причин для постановки запятой"?!

Comment: Причина обособления, как и вид синтаксической конструкции, указаны предельно ясно.  Дел не в краткости ответа, а в его содержании.  Или Вам есть чего добавить?

Comment: Причин для обособления нет. Два _разных_ обстоятельства рядом, первое нераспространенное, второе даже уточняющим назвать нельзя. Пожалуй, обособление можно даже за ошибку счесть.

Comment: Предлагаю Вам давать собственные ответы и обсуждать с обществом   их правильность. Если хотите знать мое мнение, то у Вас нет чувства языка, ВЫ не ощущаете гармоничность структуры предложения , то есть можете на одной ноте проговорить десяток слов и при этом сослаться на правило об отсутствии уточнения. Нет тут уточнения,  оборот обособляется в силу своей распространенности, а также потому, что  содержит дополнительные сведения по отношению к основному содержанию предложения. В общем, не быть Вам писателем, красоты слога не чувствуете.

Comment: Мадам, так и знал: опять пошли "ноты". Нота – это тон, только наоборот? Обособление оборота "в силу распространенности" диктуется не нотами и тонами – причина этого чисто визуальная. Чтоб было легче читать. А вы думали, опять паузы и тоны?

Comment: Niemand, неужели Вам поговорить не с кем, выберите себе другого собеседника. Меня же ваше мнение  о  русском правописании может интересовать исключительно при наличии ссылки  на Розенталя или Лопатина (вдруг Вам там что-нибудь неясно). Тогда пожалуйста, обращайтесь, помогу разобраться (надо же всё-таки людям помогать).

Comment: Вряд ли поможете, поскольку ваша тема – паузы и тоны.

Comment: @Niemand, Вы опять, имхо, переходите на личности. Если вы считаете ответ недостаточно подробным, то это можно выразить без намеков на ваши предыдущие разборки. По сути же ответ в данном случае достаточен.  Да, модераторы, а иногда и участники, ), случается, абсолютизирует требование давать развернутые ответы со ссылками (сейчас уже меньше, по счастью), но принцип разумной достаточности никто не отменял. Если из ответа понятна идея, зацепка, по которой самостоятельно можно легко найти исчерпывающий ответ, то копипастить сюда все подробности нет никакой необходимости.

Comment: Другое дело, насколько ответ правилен. Но это уж отдельный разговор. Да, мне кажется тут есть доля субъективности. Мне кажется, обособление зависит от авторской интонации.

Comment: @Morkovkin, обособление обстоятельственных оборотов считается факультативным, но в каждом случае следует учитывать дополнительные факторы, в том числе КОНТЕКСТ для выражения нужной семантики и структуру для удобного чтения предложения.  Мне кажется, что основным сообщением является то, что девушка уже прежде прошла огромную школу в ансамбле "Юг"., а под чьим руководством - это попутная информация.

Comment: @Sibylla Так никто же не возражает против дополнительных факторов. Я же говорю, что это дело субъективное.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что проблема возникает из-за неудачного построения фразы.

Ну напишите в другом порядке:

***Но прежде девушка прошла огромную школу в ансамбле "Юг" под руководством главного балетмейстера РДК Инны Викторовны.***

И по-русски - и вопросов по пунктуации не возникает... 
Могут возразить, что в таком случае получается, что это ансамбль - "под руководством", а не "школа". Но в таком случае исходная фраза вообще никуда не годится. Если в ней упоминается ансамбли и "руководство", то просто-таки необходимо дать четкую границу (если она есть и существенна). Потому что всё равно воспринимается так, что руководство ансамблем и есть руководство "девушкой". Иначе фраза совсем уж двусмысленная.

Если уж и это неубедительно, можно написать так:
***Но прежде девушка под руководством главного балетмейстера РДК Инны Викторовны прошла огромную школу в ансамбле "Юг".*** 
Запятые не нужны.

Исходя из всего сказанного полагаю обособление оборота и в исходной фразе совершенно не обязательным. Но всё же лучше её переделать (если есть возможность) - по любому из предложенных вариантов.